# Omniauth Identity redirect after create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth

I'm trying to have it so that a new identity/user is directed to a "success" page while a returning user is brought to a "welcome back" page.
I'm using Omniauth Identity **only** (no devise), so there is no create action in my controller.

I have tried adding:

config/initializers/omniauth.rb

```
on_registration: IdentitiesController.action(:new_account)
```

and then
identities_controller.rb

```
def new_account
  redirect_to confirmation_path
end
```

but that doesn't work. The only way I've found to manipulate anything only after a creation of an identity/user is after_create in the model, but I know you can't redirect from there.

I know I could just add a column to my identity table for first time login, but I'd rather not. I'm sure there has to be a much simpler way.

Comment: You did not show much code here. It is possible to ask `@user.new_record?` so maybe you can use that. Also, do you update user after she logs in (for example columns like `current_sign_in_at`, `sign_in_count`) ? If so, you can compare created_at and updated_at attributes of the user...

Comment: No, there isn't a column for current_sign_in, just for created_at. Is `.new_record?` a thing for ruby (in other words, NOT devise)? If it is, I can use that, I just never heard of it.

Comment: `.new_record?` is from `Activerecord::Base` http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/new_record%3F

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I ended up going off of the 'created_at' in the users table. I just added a simple

```
if user.created_at > 1.minute.ago
```

to the sessions controller.